# Equivalent of jQuery getScript() in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Does anyone know if ExtJS (Sencha) has a command that dynamically loads a script?

It would be the equivalent of jQuery's `$.getScript()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use function

```
Ext.Loader.loadScript
```

Answer (score 2):

Ext uses `Ext.require`, but as far as I know, you have to tell it a little bit about where to look. You also have to be using the `Ext.loader()`, and last I checked they recommended against using it in production sites.

Loader also needs you to have an `Ext.viewport`

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Loader

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
    Ext.Loader.setPath("Pie","js/Pie"); //Project paths for the loaders
    Ext.require(['Pie.viewport']);//Hey this just loaded via ajax!
    Ext.create('Pie.panel');//Awesome, this came from ajax, 
                            //and created itself on the callback!

})
```

I think this is limited in that you have to be calling an actual object though.

Answer (score 0):

Ext.js uses a concept of 'requires' to dynamically load scripts.

You can use the Ext.loader class in the following way, but you need to make sure loader is set to enabled: true, to ensure it's dynamic loading is used:

```
Ext.require('Ext.window.Window');
```

You can also use `Ext.create("Ext.class.bla", {})` which dynamically loads the class and any dependences.